# Is it possible to integrate Kerberos authentication into Jetty 6?

Tags: jetty, kerberos, jaas, gssapi

We currently have an application that runs an embedded jetty 6.1.14 server to which we need to add authentication via Kerberos.  I'm new to Kerberos, which makes the task about 100x harder that maybe it should be.  I've scoured the internet and have found conflicting [reports as to whether or not it is even possible](http://www.servlets.com/archive/servlet/ReadMsg?msgId=525726&listName=jetty-discuss) but nothing much to provides guidance as to how to proceed.

I've managed to have the server basically be able to authenticate the users via kerberos but can't find away to have the client automatically send its kerberos ticket: I have to use the from auth-method, though there are hints that this may be using filters, which are very poorly documented.

My question - and I apologize for it being a bit vague, I've not been this exasperated in quite a long time - is to request some guidance for plugging in kerberos authentication without login forms in Jetty 6?  Or am I just out of luck?  Has anyone added this type of authentication to jetty 6?

Answer (score 0):

If Jetty supports Servlet Filters (JSR-53), then this open source project http://spnego.sourceforge.net might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prepare your domain environment first. Make sure that your server if part of your domain (joined it). Then you have to create an machine account and assign an SPN. If you have done that, create a keytab for that account. From now on a client will be able to search for the host in the domain and create a ticket for. Then comes Jetty into play.